# Data and value props in the donut example as in what kind of data and value is passed can someone please give an example for it

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiWyk.png)

Need help with the data and the value props . An example would be very helpful for the same.

I need help with the data and the value prop . An example for data and value prop would be very useful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.